# Error "The parameter redirect_uri is required"

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

i am using allauth app. but when i am trying to login using faceook than it is showing me a error **The parameter redirect_url is required** But i already given a redirect url to it.[Error while logging in using facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN3DF.png)

[Redirect uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sDfI.png)

login code

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:420px;top:118px;height:400px;width:200px;" id="login">
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<label style="position:absolute;left:60px;top:50px;color:red;">Username</label>
<p style="position:absolute;left:160px;top:43px;">{{ form.username }}</p>

<label style="position:absolute;left:64px;top:111px;color:red;">Password</label>
<p style="position:absolute;left:160px;top:103px;">{{ form.password }}</p>

<input  style="position:absolute;left:210px;top:163px;height:36px;width:80px;background-color: #c52d2f;border-radius: 6px;color:white;" type="Submit" value="Login"/>
<a style="position:absolute;left:64px;top:171px;font-size:15px;font-weight:800;" href="{% url 'new' %}">Reset Password</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={{ 198608780589573 }}&amp;scope={{ scope }}&amp;redirect_uri="{{ "http://127.0.0.1:8000/about_us" }}">Login using Facebook</a>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show sample code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in a href tag :

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=198608780589573&amp;scope={{ scope }}&amp;redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/about_us'">Login using Facebook</a>
```

You are using {{ }} curly brackets in a wrong way. If there is a Django variable,then only you should use {{ }},otherwise just double quotes are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ var }}` is Django template language to pass variable from view function to your html.  Please change your code to this...

```
&redirect_uri=127.0.0.1:8000/about_us
```

Comment: can  you give me that url after you click that link | copy it form your browser and show it here...

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=198608780589573&scope=&&redirect_uri=

Comment: @MonuThakur It's still empty why ? I told you to put `&redirect_uri=127.0.0.1:8000/about_us` in your html code...

Comment: i have put that code to redirect_uri but it is not showing it on browser url i don't know why.

Comment: Don't know why please clear all cache and try again.

Comment: when i am trying this **redirect_uri="{% url 'localhost:8000/about_us' %}"** it is showing me error **NoReverseMatch at /users/login/

u'localhost' is not a registered namespace**

Comment: well in that case try to put your view function... normally I like to write `{% url 'name_of_the_view_functoin' %}` or `{% url 'polls:index' %}` you know what I'm talking right ?

Comment: issue is resolved now i have generated new id ad secret key and now it is working nicely thanks for your support.